# I see only white screen after deployment while I can see app running fine

Tags: amazon-ec2, vuejs2, visual-studio-2019, web-deployment

I am working on a Vue project in visual studio. I was able to build and run my application locally without any issues. So I copied dist folder contents and added them to server. I tested my application with the appropriate url but I am unable to see the pages. It is displaying white screen only. The server is AWS. I also gave IIS users permissions if that is the issues.
Can you please help me on this??

[Text file for testing returned good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIMqf.png)

[Dashboard returning white screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azmeN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check console logs? Are you sure everything was uploaded correctly?

Comment: thanks for reminding me this. I got 4 "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" errors but there are no details in there...how do I know why this error is thrown?

Comment: hmm are you sure that these files are on the server? Might .htaccess from an above folder override rules for paths?

Comment: Yes they are..I just checked them and they are all there

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding a **vue.config.js** file next to **package.json**.
The problem was, I deployed my project in a sub folder and it was looking for "**BASE_URL**" in index.html which is pointing to wwwroot folder instead of subfolder.

So for that I added

```
 module.exports = {
    publicPath: './'
};
```

to vue.config.js file which magically resolved the issue !!!